# Entity Framework + conditionally appended Where() clauses

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

This is driving me nuts. What am I missing here. I'm using EF and if I have code like the following:

```
using (LexiconEntities ctx = new LexiconEntities())
{
  var query = from w in ctx.Words
        select new WordEntryDataModel
        {
          Word = w.Anagram,
          NumOfAnagrams = w.NumAnagrams.Value,
          Length = w.Length.Value,
          ...
        };

  SearchCriterion c1 = new SearchCriterion();
  SearchCriterion c2 = new SearchCriterion();

  c1.MinValue = 3; 
  c1.MaxValue = 3;

  c2.MinValue = 4;
  c2.MaxValue = 4;

  query = query.Where(w => w.Length >= c1.MinValue && w.Length <= c1.MaxValue);
  query = query.Where(w => w.NumOfAnagrams >= c2.MinValue && w.NumOfAnagrams <= c2.MaxValue);

  ...
}
```

And when I debug the query, I get the proper results (8 records). This also works as expected in Linqpad (which frickin' rocks).

But if I construct the search criteria as a List of criterion objects, and I dynamically add on Where() clauses by iterating over the search criteria as follows:

```
  foreach (SearchCriterion c in criteria.SearchCriteria)
  {
    switch (c.Type)
    {
      case SearchCriterionType.WordLength:
        query = query.Where(w => w.Length >= c.MinValue && w.Length <= c.MaxValue);
        break;
      case SearchCriterionType.NumberOfAnagrams:
        query = query.Where(w => w.NumOfAnagrams >= c.MinValue && w.NumOfAnagrams <= c.MaxValue);
        break;
      ...
      case SearchCriterionType.NumberOfVowels:
        query = query.Where(w => w.NumOfVowels >= c.MinValue && w.NumOfVowels <= c.MaxValue);
        break;
    }
  }
  ...
```

I get the totally different (and incorrect) results. I've debugged the switch statement and my search criteria has two *properly* constructed criterion objects set to correct values. There's something about the conditionally added where clauses that my query doesn't like.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, the expression trees must be different. Easiest way to debug is probably to look at the generated SQL (`ObjectQuery.ToTraceString()`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closure.  Assign c to a local variable within the loop.  Also see my SO [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709324/entity-framework-views-and-linq-where/3710044#3710044)

Comment: That worked thanks! I don't understand why, but cool. The concept of closure hurts my brain.